# Update Manager Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts-development

Tags: upgrade, update-manager

I am trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS to 20.04 LTS using the GUID at [Upgrade Ubuntu desktop](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-upgrading-ubuntu-desktop#1-before-you-start). I followed steps 1, 2, and 3, but no option to upgrade appeared. I then typed `upgrade-manager -d` in my terminal, but got the following error:

```
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts-development. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
```

My internet connection is fine and I am not running a proxy. I searched for similar topics but none of them seemed to resolve the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 16 to 20 and the system did not restart.

I do not recommend doing this upgrade. It is best to make a backup and install from scratch.

I will show you how to mount a pendrive for installation:

Download the ISO from the website: https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Place the USB stick on the machine and identify, open the bash terminal:
Put the pendrive on the machine and the command

```
df -h
```

For example, I see at the end the line:
**/dev/sdc1** 336M 336M 0 100% /media/user/Debian 10.4.0 amd64 n

This is my flash drive on **/dev/sdc** *yours can be /dev/sda-b-c-or-n*

After making sure what your device is, give the command:

```
dd if=/home/Chase/Downloads/ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc
```

After press Enter Wait until it finishes, this process will take time, all files will be copied to the flash drive, it may take about 10 minutes, wait.
When the prompt returns, just give the command

```
sync
```

Restart your machine with a boot on the flash drive and enjoy!